# MongoContext passing model object and collection name

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api2

My current working code `MongoContext'

```
namespace MC.API
{
    using MongoDB.Driver;
    using MongoDB.Driver.GridFS;
    using MC.API.Properties;
    using MC.DataModel.Models;

    public class MongoContext
    {
        public IMongoDatabase Database;

        public GridFSBucket ImagesBucket { get; set; }

        public MongoContext()
        {
            var connectionString = Settings.Default.MCConnectionString;
            var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));
            settings.ClusterConfigurator = builder => builder.Subscribe(new Log4NetMongoEvents());
            var client = new MongoClient(settings);
            Database = client.GetDatabase(Settings.Default.MCDatabaseName);
            ImagesBucket = new GridFSBucket(Database);
        }

        public IMongoCollection<Deal> Deals => Database.GetCollection<Deal>("deals");
    }
}
```

and I create instance in controller

```
public MongoContext Context = new MongoContext();
```

I want to have a possibility pass `collectionName` and `model object` that will more flexible

```
  public IMongoCollection<model object> Objs => Database.GetCollection<model object>(collectionName);
```

Comment: What is the relationship between Obj and Deal?

Comment: Deal is my object or class